# Pycharm shortcuts and themes

Tags: pycharm

I recently migrated from pydev to pycharm. I have a couple of questions

1. In pydev I select a block of code and I can enclose it in a try except block  or an if else block with simply Ctrl + 1. How can I do it in pycharm if it could be done.
2. How do I import a pycharm theme in ubuntu? I put xml files from https://github.com/d1ffuz0r/pycharm-themes in ~/.PyCharm20/config/colors, but none of them seem to show up in the appearance under settings, even after restarting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. See [Surrounding Blocks of Code with Language Constructs](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html).
2. These themes are in old format (`.xml`). New PyCharm versions read themes in `.icls` format. New themes appear in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Eclipse before, and I didn't want to study the shortcuts in PyCharm.
Then, I found there is a way to configure your shortcuts,
File--Settings--IDE settings-- Keymap--> choose Eclipse or other shortcut configure as you like.